# How to set border-bottom style for <strong> text

Tags: html, css

On this page (http://nate.fm/articles) I have two different articles listed. One is bold and one is regular. They are both links with a 3px border-bottom. However, the bold font's border-bottom is pushed down slightly lower than the regular font.

Can anyone tell me where that extra space is being defined in the CSS?

Comment: I actually see it fine on Firefox, what browser are you using?

Comment: In Chrome there is a difference: http://nate.fm/i/9xF5ar-z.png

Comment: Hmm I didn't see the image. Which version of chrome and operating system are you using? The difference in my chrome 53.0.2785.143  window 10 is not so big as in your image.

Comment: Also I have asked a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40124379/3429430) related to your website, which might be of interest to you. That question is about a different problem though.

Answer (score 1):

> However, the bold font's border-bottom is pushed down slightly lower than the regular font.

No. Under the link `Like` the border is 7px below the character the first character `L` and under the link `Pro-Life vs Pro-Birth` the border is again 7px below the character `P`. Perhaps you are getting deluded by the `g` in `Light`.

P.S: I checked the distances by printing screen and pasting to photoshop.

Comment: If you view it in Chrome, you'll see the difference. There is a real difference, not just a perception. I added a lowercase "g" to "Pro-Life vs." line and it doesn't change or push down the underline. This is an actual issue with the bold font in the first line.

Comment: I checked in chrome/windows10. The `border-bottom` of both the links is exactly `7px` below their corresponding first characters. Adding `g` to `Pro-Life` would not push the the underline -- this is the expected behavior. If you want I can upload zoomed images showing 7px distance with marquee tool of Photoshop.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this, but if you look at this image (http://nate.fm/i/J61MU2_z.png) you can see that there is definitely a difference. I understand that the border-bottom is 7px below, but my question is why does it now show up as 7px in the top link?

Comment: @NateHanson Does the issue persist if you change the `font-family`? You can check this by changing the `font-family` in dev tools. I think the _Crimson Text_ font you are using is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems those are actually different font variants: The font-weights are 400 and 700, so probably the 700-font has a slightly different (descender) size/height to fit those bolder letters into the line.

Comment: Could you tell me where you see the 400 and the 700 being defined? I cannot even find that.

Comment: In the developer tools of the browser - in my case Firefox/Mac, when you select the 'a' tag and switch to the "fonts" tab in the developer tools (could be named slightly different - I have the German version here)